# Select records around given record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ranking

I have a ranking in my application, every user has points and can see at any time the current ranking of the entire database

Now I need to display the top 5 and the 5 around the current user, something like this:

- 1º (100pts)
- 2º (90pts)
- 3º (79pts)
- 4º (79pts)
- 5º (60pts)
- ...
- 1200º (6pts)
- 1201º (6pts)
- 1202º (5pts)
- 1203º (5pts) <- You
- 1204º (5pts)
- 1205º (5pts)
- 1206º (5pts)

How can I make this? Assuming points can be changed at all times and it is very costly to recount every position on point change

Comment: Which database do you use for your points?

Comment: Postgresql on production, sqlite on development

Comment: Set up PostgreSQL for development and then do some searching on "PostgreSQL leaderboard".